# Developer ID signed application - Code Signing

Tags: macos, code-signing

The Mac AppStore version works perfectly. The Developer ID signed application crashes on launch.

All the checks after archiving the app pass after i export it the .app won't open. If I run lldb it says it has a problem with code signing.

Running:
`spctl -a -v app.app` returns the expected result ( `app.app: accepted
source=Developer ID` )

Exploring the package and running directly the executable prints: `[1]    25438 killed`

If I build and run from Xcode the app works without a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like Apple changed their mind and the Apple Map entitlement for non AppStore apps is NOT allowed and it will make your application crash on launch.